# SIGNAL HELP: What signal a child would send to its parent when it is about to crash?

Tags: signals, ptrace

I am tracing a program using ptrace and that program crashes while running. I have written a code that prints stack trace of a pid. I am stuck at the point that I don't know when it is about to crash and when should I print the stack trace.

Could anyone suggest me what signal a dying program send to its parent? So I can write a signal handler.

Answer (score 0):

The tracer may call `waitpid(child_pid, ...)`, when the waited tracee gets killed by signal, `waitpid` would return `WIFSIGNALED`, so you can add your code there.